# Batch Arrays addition

Tags: arrays, batch-file, addition

Hi im trying to addition to arrays but my code is wrong.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /p filas=ingrese el numero de filas: 
set /p columnas=ingrese el numero de columnas: 

for /l %%i in (0,1,%filas%) do (
  for /l %%j in (0,1,%columnas%) do (   
    set array[%%i,%%j]=!random! 
    set array2[%%i,%%j]=!random!
  )
)

set array array2
pause

echo addition
for /l %%i in (0,1,%filas%) do (
  for /l %%j in (0,1,%columnas%) do (   
    set /a arreglo[%%i,%%j]= !array[%%i,%%j]!+!array2[%%i,%%j]!    
  )
)
set arrreglo
pause

exit
```

Comment: Hi there. Please reformat the code section in your post. Makes it easier for everyone to read and help.

Comment: Your code has been placed into a code box accordingly. Incidentally, `set array` will output each variable name beginning with array, and it's associated value, so adding `array2` is unnecessary, and I'm going to surmise invalid.

Comment: The best practice is that variable names include only alphanumeric characters and the underscore **`_`** character. Variable names that include spaces and other special characters, are difficult to use and should be avoided.

Comment: You also appear to have a typo in your code: `set arrreglo` when your variable's name is `arreglo`

Answer (score 0):

First problem: Replace each `,` in every `var[%%i,%%j]` with a non-separator character. Separator characters are <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>;</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd>. I'd suggest `_` in this case (as described by Compo)

Second problem: Your `set arrreglo` statement that shows the results of the addition contains too many `r`s (typo)

There is no need to include the <kbd>!</kbd> in the `set /a ...+...` statement as the `set /a` syntax allows the variablenames to be used unadorned. The fact that the value of (eg) `array[...]` is not varied in the loop should indicate that the <kbd>!</kbd> is unlikely to be required.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon my comments, fixing your typo, removing the unnecessary `!`'s from your `Set /A`'s, and adding some validation to the user input, here's an example:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:AskInput
Rem Ensure variable names are undefined.
For %%I In (filas testf columnas testc)Do Set "%%I="

Rem Ask for numeric input for filas and verify as valid.
Set /P "filas=ingrese el numero de filas: "
Set /A "testf=!filas!" 2>NUL||Set "testf="
If Not "!testf!"=="!filas!" GoTo AskInput

Rem Ask for numeric input for columnas and verify as valid.
Set /P "columnas=ingrese el numero de columnas: "
Set /A "testc=!columnas!" 2>NUL||Set "testc="
If Not "!testc!"=="!columnas!" GoTo AskInput

Rem Undefine superfluous variables.
For /F "Delims==" %%I In ('Set test 2^>NUL')Do Set "%%I="

Rem Define array/array2 variables.
For /F "Delims==" %%I In ('Set array 2^>NUL')Do Set "%%I="
For /L %%I In (0,1,%filas%)Do For /L %%J In (0,1,%columnas%
)Do Set /A array[%%I_%%J]=!RANDOM!,array2[%%I_%%J]=!RANDOM!

Rem Show array/array2 variables with their values.
Set array
Pause

Echo Addition
Rem Define arreglo variables.
For /F "Delims==" %%I In ('Set arreglo 2^>NUL')Do Set "%%I="
For /L %%I In (0,1,%filas%)Do For /l %%J In (0,1,%columnas%
)Do Set /A arreglo[%%I_%%J]=array[%%I_%%J]+array2[%%I_%%J]

Rem Show arreglo variables with their values.
Set arreglo
Pause
```